# how to create an incremental sum on Excel using VBA

Tags: function, excel, sum, vba

here is the situ ation I have many sheets all displaying the same columns in the same order and they have different data in them, Im trying to write a Macro to insert a column next to the cost one and to create a runing summ or incremental sum, this column will then be copied to a new sheet later on. After a tries I have managed to get close to my goal, the problem is that my macro does the same calculation over and over again, without summing the cost column. it gets clearer if you look at the code I'm posting below. all help to solve the problem would be appreciated.

```
Sub IncCost()

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Columns("H:H").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("H1").FormulaR1C1 = "Incremental cost"
    Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = Cells(2, 7)
    Range("H3").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & Cells(3, 7) & "+" & Cells(2, 8)
    Range("H3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("H3:H" & r.Rows.Count)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Range("h3:h" & r.rows.count).formular1c1 = "=RC[-1]+R[-1]C"
```

Comment: thanks JosieP, The problem with this method is that once I copy the colunm on a new shhet I end up copying the equation as well not the values.

Comment: you can copy and paste special-values or your code can convert the formulas to values

Comment: I had no idea this was even possible, how do you do this trick ?

Comment: Which one? To do it manually, click the Paste dropdown, choose paste special, then select Values from the options. In code assign the .Value property of the range to the .Value property of the range